# How can I handle an ADFS redirect to a different host in an ajax call?

Tags: ajax, jquery, cross-domain, adfs2.0

I am having a problem with ADFS redirects in ajax calls. When an ajax call gets back a redirect from ADFS it will fail because our ADFS is running under a different host.

I'm using jQuery to do the ajax call. Setting crossDomain to true did not solve the problem.

Also, in the error function I pass to $.ajax, I don't (know how to) get enough information to determine that this problem has occured. The `ajaxOptions` parameter is "error" and the `thrownError` parameter = "".

How can I prevent or adequately handle this error?

I am using jQuery 1.5.1 and ADFS 2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ADFS session expires and causes error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668751/adfs-session-expires-and-causes-error)

Comment: same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746222/ad-fs-2-0-authentication-and-ajax the problem is ADFS uses an intermediate form that AJAX treats as the response